# Edit personal information page , not able to edit user profile properties

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

Facing issue with Editing user information,

My requirement is user should able to edit personal information from 
`http://<siteurl>/_layouts/useredit.aspx?ID=1`, However I am just seeing Title and Attachment option only.

I have already done setting like: "Allow users to edit values for this property" is selected in central admin, as well in Web application permission is given to Edit personal information.
Still not able to see the properties which are allowed to edit.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

What permission did you grant to the user.? 
Even when you enable “allow users to edit  values for this property” option, only users with the Manage Profile permission can edit any property value for any user.

You can find out that only three permission levels have this permission. Try to grant one of these permissions to the user, then check the effect.

**Site permissions Permission**

**Permission:** Edit Personal User Information

**Description:** Users can change their own user information, such as adding a picture.

**Dependent permissions:** Browse User Information, Open

Included in these permission levels by default : Contribute, Design, Full Control

For more information about User permissions and permission levels (SharePoint Foundation 2010), please refer to the following article: [User permissions and permission levels (SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx)

**EDIT:**

When you create a web application that is not connected to an User Profile Service Application users are able to edit the information from My Settings. Default Contribute Group allows user to edit their information so everything works normally. Users are editing now in the WebApplication_Content database, table AllUsers.

In the next situation :

1) connect your above created application to a User Profile Service Application (regardless the fact no connection (e.g AD) exists)

2) create a new web application and connect it to User Profile Service Application

users can no longer edit /_layout/userdisp.aspx User Information page just because system now users UserProfile Profile DB Users and they can edit only from My Site.

The user information is controlled through your My Site profile, not the local Site Collection profile (My Settings is the local site collection profile).

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f95ad1e4-ba95-40a9-bd3e-cc499da75c14/sharepoint-server-2010-my-settings-not-editable?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: Yes, I have given these permissions to the users, still not able to edit in Edit Personal Information dialog.

Comment: Now you can check my answer, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify (in the tags) that you have your site connected to the User Profile Service and most likely use My Sites - then this is the standard behavior on the Site Collection level. All user profile property editing must be managed throught the My Site Host.

Comment: means, from My Setting->Edit Item shows Edit Profile Setting , will not be able to edit any property?